# Get the correct loop value during callbacks

Tags: node.js, for-loop, callback

I am trying to poll multiple sites but when I try to print the array index it doesn't return the true index.

```
   var request = require('request');
var opt=['https://dev.twitter.com','https://developer.foursquare.com/','https://developers.facebook.com'];
function req()
{
for(i=0;i<opt.length;i++)
{

request(opt[i], function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Yes "+i)
  }
  else
    console.log("No");
})
}
}
setInterval(req,3000);
```

Whats the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an asynchronous function call in a loop. This means the loop will continue while the request is being processed and will result in a wrong loop index.

If you want to get the correct index you have to either make the function call synchronous or you have to control the flow of your functions.

You can do this with the module [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries)

Here an example.

```
var request = require('request')
 , async = require('async');

var opt = ['https://dev.twitter.com','https://developer.foursquare.com/','https://developers.facebook.com'];

function req() {

    var count = 0;

    // Use async to loop each opt value in series
    async.eachSeries(opt, function(entry, callback) {
        count++;

        request(entry, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log('Yes ' + count)
            }
            else {
                console.log('No');
            }

            callback(); 
        });
    }, function(err) {
         console.log('We are done!');
    });
}

setInterval(req,3000);
```